# Keep adjacent visible when other is hovered

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Look at this example : https://jsfiddle.net/ptss94gw/

Is it possible with only CSS to keep the `.more-icons` div visible when hovered outside the `.h-icon` ?

Comment: Unclear.  .... Do you mean at all time or hovering something else or ... else ?

Comment: Hovering over .more-icons element for example

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about this?

What I've done is change the hover state to belong to `.icon-line` instead of the anchors themselves.

```
.icon-line {
    float: left;
    a {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        position: relative;   
    }
    &:hover .h-icon {
        i {
            opacity: 1;
        }
        & ~ .more-icons {
            opacity: inherit;
        }
    }
}
.h-icon {
     i {
         display: block;
     }
    &.test {
        float: right;
        display: inline-block;
        width: 16px;
        height: 16px;
        background:blue;
        i {
             opacity: 0;
        }
        .main-ico {
            width:16px;
            height:16px;
            background:red;
        }
    }
}
.more-icons {
    float: left;
    height: 16px;
    padding-right: 8px;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: -10;
    a {
        display: block;
        float: left;
        height: 14px;
        width: 14px;
        text-align: center;
        margin: 2px 8px;
        z-index: -1;
    }
    i {
        display: block;
    }
    .icon-1 {
      width:16px;
      height: 16px;
      background:red;
    }
    .icon-2 {
      width:16px;
      height: 16px;
      background:blue;
    }
    .icon-3 {
      width:16px;
      height: 16px;
      background:green;
    }
}
```

```css
.icon-line {
  float: left; }
  .icon-line a {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative; }
    .icon-line:hover .h-icon i {
      opacity: 1; }
      .icon-line:hover .h-icon ~ .more-icons {
        opacity: inherit; }

.h-icon i {
  display: block; }
  .h-icon.test {
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    background: blue; }
    .h-icon.test i {
      opacity: 0; }
      .h-icon.test .main-ico {
        width: 16px;
        height: 16px;
        background: red; }

.more-icons {
  float: left;
  height: 16px;
  padding-right: 8px;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -10; }
  .more-icons a {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    height: 14px;
    width: 14px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 2px 8px;
    z-index: -1; }
    .more-icons i {
      display: block; }
      .more-icons .icon-1 {
        width: 16px;
        height: 16px;
        background: red; }
        .more-icons .icon-2 {
          width: 16px;
          height: 16px;
          background: blue; }
          .more-icons .icon-3 {
            width: 16px;
            height: 16px;
            background: green; }
```

```html
<div class="icon-line">
  <div class="h-icon test">
   <a href="#">
    <i class="main-ico"></i>
   </a>
  </div><!-- .s-icon -->
  <div class="more-icons">
   <a href="#">
    <i class="icon-1"></i>
   </a>
   <a href="#">
    <i class="icon-2"></i>
   </a>
   <a href="#">
    <i class="icon-3"></i>
   </a>
  </div>
  
 </div>
```

Comment: Well the problem is that I'm trying to keep those links clickable ( those inside .more-icons )

Comment: @WilsonG Interesting... There's some weird z-indexing going on.  Is there more to the code not included in the question, or can I feel free to manipulate the z-indexes?

Comment: Oops forgot to remove z-indexes( was testing some other solution).

Comment: @WilsonG Ah.  Well, in any case, setting the z-index can be done on hover as well.  Just an FYI: https://jsfiddle.net/7Lk9ptxx/

Comment: Yes, but now hover works over the whole wrapper.